# How to pass data from input field to parent component using context API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have an input field in child component. If you type in valid wallet address it should display wallet balance in parent component.

I don't know how to pass that e.target.value we are reading from input field.

I tried to do this function in parent component - Dashboard.

```
const [walletBalance, setWalletBalance] = useState('');

const getWalletBalance = async () => {
try {
  const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'ws://localhost:3000');
  for (const wallet of dummyWallets) {
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(wallet.address);
    console.log(balance);
    const balanceConvertedFromWeiToEth = await Web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether');
    const shortenedBalance =
      balanceConvertedFromWeiToEth.length >= 10
        ? balanceConvertedFromWeiToEth.slice(0, 10)
        : balanceConvertedFromWeiToEth;
    setWalletBalance(shortenedBalance);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  throw new Error('No wallet found');
}
```

};

```
render ( 
   <p>Wallet balance: {walletBalance}</p>
```

and then pass this function down to child component with input field (need to prop drill 3 times for that) and in child component say:

```
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');


const handleInputChange = (e) => {
setInputText(e.target.value);
  if (inputText === wallet.address) {
    getWalletBalance()
}
```

};

```
render (
   <input value={inputText} onChange={handleInputChange} />
```

)

It didn't work. No errors. Just nothing happens.

Then I thought that I need to do the other way around: Instead of trying to pass getWalletBalance() down as props, I need to read data from input field and pass that data to parent component, because parent needs to have access to the input field and read from it to be able to display wallet balance in parent.

I've also tried to create context:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { dummyWallets } from '../mocks/dummyWallets';
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

export const WalletContext = createContext();

```
 // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
 export const TransactionProvider = ({ children }) => {
 const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
 const [walletBalance, setWalletBalance] = useState('');

 const handleInputChange = async (e) => {
  setInputText(e.target.value);

  const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'ws://localhost:3000');

  for (const wallet of dummyWallets) {
  if (inputText === wallet.address) {
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(wallet.address);
    console.log(balance);
    const balanceConvertedFromWeiToEth = await Web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether');
    const shortenedBalance =
      balanceConvertedFromWeiToEth.length >= 10
        ? balanceConvertedFromWeiToEth.slice(0, 10)
        : balanceConvertedFromWeiToEth;
    setWalletBalance(shortenedBalance);
  }
}
```

};

```
  return (
    <WalletContext.Provider
      value={{ walletBalance, handleInputChange, inputText, setInputText, 
setWalletBalance }}>
      {children}
    </WalletContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then pass handleInputChange to onChange in child component and inputText as value, then use walletBalance in parent component.
All context things walletBalance, handleInputChange, inputText, setInputText and setWalletBalance threw undefined error.

Here is child component consuming data from context:

```
import React, { FC, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import { Button, InputAdornment, Box, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import TextField from '@eyblockchain/ey-ui/core/TextField';
import { Search } from '@material-ui/icons';
import SvgEthereum from '../../../images/icon/Ethereum';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { Theme } from '@material-ui/core';
import { dummyWallets } from '../../../shared/mocks/dummyWallets';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import { WalletContext } from '../../../shared/context/WalletContext';

const etherIconBorderColor = '#eaeaf2';
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  etherIconGridStyle: {
    padding: '16px 0 0 0'
  },
  etherIconStyle: {
    fontSize: '220%',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.primary.light,
    borderTop: `solid 1px ${etherIconBorderColor}`,
    borderBottom: `solid 1px ${etherIconBorderColor}`,
    borderLeft: `solid 1px ${etherIconBorderColor}`,
    padding: '5px 0 0 0',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      fontSize: '150%',
      lineHeight: '43px'
    }
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  searchIconStyle: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.light
  }
}));

const onSubmitHandler = () => {
  return;
};

const SearchInputForm: FC<any> = (props) => {
  const { walletBalance, handleInputChange, inputText } = useContext(WalletContext);

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}
      initialValues={{ name: '' }}
      render={({ values }) => {
        return (
          <Form>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={1} className={classes.etherIconGridStyle}>
                <Box className={classes.etherIconStyle}>
                  <SvgEthereum />
                </Box>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={11}>
                <Field
                  required
                  name="name"
                  placeholder={props.placeholdervalue}
                  value={inputText}
                  component={TextField}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  InputProps={{
                    endAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <Search fontSize="large" className={classes.searchIconStyle} />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    )
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Box
                  display="flex"
                  justifyContent="flex-end"
                  alignItems="flex-end"
                  className={classes.buttonStyle}>
                  <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="secondary" size="large" disabled>
                    Create Alert
                  </Button>
                </Box>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default SearchInputForm;
```

Here is parent component where I pull walletBalance from context:

```
const Dashboard: FC<any> = () => {
  const { walletBalance } = useContext(WalletContext);

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <Container maxWidth={false} className={classes.dashboardContainer}>
        <Grid>
          <Box data-testid="alert-page-heading">
            <Typography variant="h3">Alerts</Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box data-testid="alert-page-subheading">
            <Typography className={classes.subHeadingStyle}>
              Monitor the Web 3.0 for interesting blockchain events
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Grid>

        <Grid container spacing={4}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
            <Box className={classes.dashboardCard}>
              <Box className={classes.searchBox}>
                <SearchTabs />
              </Box>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  justifyContent: 'space-between'
                }}>
                <Box
                  sx={{
                    height: '60%',
                    padding: '1%',
                    fontSize: 20
                  }}>
                  <a href="http://localhost:3000/" className={classes.backToAlertsLink}>
                    Back to my alerts
                  </a>
                  <p className={classes.boldText}>Recent transactions</p>
                </Box>
                <Box sx={{ height: '60%', padding: '4%', fontSize: 20 }}>
                  <span>Wallet Balance</span>
                  <span className={classes.balanceNumber}>{walletBalance} ETH</span>
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
            <Box className={classes.dashboardCard}>
              <Box sx={{ height: '60%', padding: '2%', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                Top 10 alerts
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

The problem is that I pull handleChange from context and apply to input field in child component to read the value from the input and then pull walletBalance from context in parent but that walletBalance is not updated (doesn't contain input value in it).

Can someone please share knowledge on how to read data from child component input field and display something from that in parent component?

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How are you utilizing the context? What I mean is you have mentioned the code of Provider but not of Consumer. Please show the consumer code as well.

Comment: Thank you Soheb. I've updated the post. I hope it's clear now.